# Update multiplae item in sharepoint Online list conditionally from other list

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a list a with having User Informtaion Emp ID, name, manager etc with one item for each emp ID.
 I have a second list with  emp Id leave balance as their are three types of leaves For eac emp Id There are 3 Item in list b.
 I need to update the list B with emp name list A for each emp ID .(which means list B required to update 3 time with same name.

What could be the possible solution for it without using server side code

Thanks
 Parul

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you creating a workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013. Using “Call HTTP web Service” action to loop the list B to update multiple list items.

Check the article about [how to use workflow loop through multiple SharePoint items](https://wonderlaura.com/2014/08/01/workflow-loop-through-multiple-sharepoint-items/)

In the loop stage, you can add “update list item” action as below:
[image]
You can change the relevant action and variable for your condition.